# Why isn't my custom function kicking in from my functions.php file?

Tags: php, functions, url-rewriting

We'd like to clean some of our WordPress URL's up and have some rewrites in place in the following format:

Actual URL: product-one/product-one-guides/

Actual URL: product-two/product-two-guides/

Rewritten URL: product-one/guides/

Rewritten URL: product-two/guides/

This allows us to use the same sub folder name within separate products. (no duplicate slug issues )

Anyway, I have a function in functions.php that does this:

```
// URL replaces
function updateToPerfectURLs($content) {

    $new_content = $content;

    $new_content = str_replace("/product-one-", "/", $new_content);
    $new_content = str_replace("/product-two-", "/", $new_content);

    return $new_content;
}
```

I now want to do something like this:

```
<?php updateToPerfectURLs(the_permalink())?>
```

But for some reason the replaces aren't taking place and my permalinks are still coming out like:

```
domain.com/product-one/product-one-guides
```

Can anyone think of a reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't working because you've mixed up returning values and echoing values

```
updateToPerfectURLs(the_permalink());
```

Here `updateToPerfectURLs` returns its value, but you've not printed it out. Try echo/etc

Your second problem is the opposite, `the_permalink()` doesn't return the permalink, it echos it out. So before you've even gotten into the function the permalink is printed out. Use `get_permalink()` instead,.

Finally, don't pass a function call directly into another, it makes things harder to read and debug

Giving you:

```
$permalink = get_permalink();
echo updateToPerfectURLs( $permalink );
```

Of course there is probably a better way to do this using the various filters without hardcoding product names in your function. That would be a new question you should ask! I imagine it would be useful to many people. Perhaps a rewrite endpoint would work too

Comment: Could I do it through filters in my functions.php file so I don;t have to change any references to: <?php the_permalink()?> in my theme files?

Comment: Yes, that would be a new question though, look up the filter named `the_permalink`

Comment: See you on the other side? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144125/how-can-i-modify-the-permalink-via-a-filter - Apologies, we're looking for quite a quick solution as this is the fine piece of the jigsaw before putting our website live.