# How can I modify the permalink via a filter?

Tags: php, functions, url-rewriting

I would like to make a change to the URL's in my href attribute across my while site when the_permalink is called.

For example:

```
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"
```

Can I use my functions.php file to call my custom functon which deals with the search and replaces in the URL's

```
function updateToPerfectURLs($content) {
```

Answer (score 4):

Ooops easier than I thought!

```
function edit_the_permalink($html){
    $html = updateToPerfectURLs($html);
    return $html;
}
add_filter('the_permalink', 'edit_the_permalink');
```

Comment: although perhaps `add_filter('the_permalink', 'updateToPerfectURLs');` would be simpler