# What is the action or filter for changing permalink in Edit Post/Page?

Tags: permalinks, hooks, post-editor

I know about `edit_form_after_title` hook but what about changing the permalink. How does WordPress creates permalink because that permalink and the one that `get_the_permalink` returns doesn't match? Could someone help me?

Comment: This [recent question here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189827/is-there-a-log-for-the-ajax-calls-made-when-changing-a-posts-slug/) might be somewhat related? I list there some actions/filters that might be useful for your task/debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`the_permalink`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink) filter to modify permalinks.

Take a look at the [function reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) for the same.

Code sample from the docs:

> Append the query string for the current page to permalink URLs
>
> ```
> function append_query_string($url) {
>     return add_query_arg($_GET, $url);
> }
> add_filter('the_permalink', 'append_query_string');
> ```

---

**More information on permalinks:**

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014167/general-wordpress-link-filter) (StackOverflow)
- [Here](http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/wordpress-permalinks) (Elegant Themes)
- [And here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144125/how-can-i-modify-the-permalink-via-a-filter) (WPSE)